# Google Analytics API: queryCost and resourceQuotasRemaining in response body

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In docs for [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#response-body) Response body contains `queryCost` and `resourceQuotasRemaining`. But, when I do

```
curl -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?access_token=mytoken' -d '{"reportRequests":[{"viewId":"ga:myviewId","dateRanges":[{"startDate":"2019-12-04","endDate":"2019-12-04"}],"dimensions":[{"name":"ga:campaign"},{"name":"ga:adContent"},{"name":"ga:keyword"},{"name":"ga:currencyCode"}],"dimensionFilterClauses":[{"filters":[{"dimensionName":"ga:sourceMedium","operator":"EXACT","expressions":["Yandex.Market / cpc"]}]},{"filters":[{"dimensionName":"ga:campaign","operator":"PARTIAL","expressions":["msk"]}]}],"metrics":[{"expression":"ga:goal12Completions"}],"metricFilterClauses":[{"filters":[{"metricName":"ga:goal12Completions","operator":"GREATER_THAN","comparisonValue":"0"}]}],"hideTotals":true,"hideValueRanges":true}]}'
```

response body do not contain `queryCost` and `resourceQuotasRemaining`

```
{"reports":[{"columnHeader":{"dimensions":[...],"metricHeader":{"metricHeaderEntries":[...]}},"data":{"rows":[{"dimensions":[...],"metrics":[...]}],"rowCount":1,"isDataGolden":true}}]}
```

If I add to JSON in POST `"useResourceQuotas":true`, I get error: "The request is not eligible for resource quotas. Check if account is premium and whitelisted." (code 400).
How I can get information about query cost, quotas remaining and other limit stats using API? Or it is possible only for premium accounts?

Comment: please edit your question and includ the full json data you are posting so i can test this.   remove the ...   you can leave out the view id i can add my own.

Comment: @DaImTo i am include all json without view id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pete,

Resource based quota feature is only available to Analytics 360 users.

Thanks,
Ilya

Comment: We do not use Analytics 360. Thanks Ilya, thanks @DaImTo

Answer (score 0):

your request doesn't include useResourceQuotas = true. its default false

```
{
  "reportRequests": [
    {
      "viewId": "ga:xxxx",
      "dateRanges": [
        {
          "startDate": "2019-12-04",
          "endDate": "2019-12-04"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": [
        {
          "expression": "ga:users"
        }
      ],
      "hideTotals": true,
      "hideValueRanges": true
    }
  ],
  "useResourceQuotas": true
}
```

Result

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "columnHeader": {
        "metricHeader": {
          "metricHeaderEntries": [
            {
              "name": "ga:users",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "rows": [
          {
            "metrics": [
              {
                "values": [
                  "1298"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "rowCount": 1,
        "isDataGolden": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "resourceQuotasRemaining": {
    "dailyQuotaTokensRemaining": 100000,
    "hourlyQuotaTokensRemaining": 25000
  }
}
```

## useResourceQuotas

Doesn't work with every request.   I would suggest that you go though yours adding different things to see what the exact problem is.  Start by removing all those filters.   Once you figure out exactly which one is giving you the error with the userREsourceQuotas let me know and i will ping the team about having the documentation updated.  It doesnt say currently that there should be an issue with using it with anything.  I cant test your request I dont have any accounts with goals setup like that that i could test with.

Comment: I tried removing the filters, but got the same answer. Then I used the JSON from your example with my view id, but the situation has not changed. In both cases, I checked JSON on https://jsoneditoronline.org/. Also in both cases, if I removed `"useResourceQuotas": true` then the correct response was returned.

Comment: I have contacted the team to find out if there is any reason you would need to be white listed .   My account is probably white listed for everything which is why it works for me without any issues.   I will let you know if i hear back.

Comment: The team says the error message hasn't been updated.    I'm trying to get some more information on what the correct error message is in that case